# Adjust dropbox in iphone

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I have studied a lot of codes about dropbox and I already create an app that is sharing files to dropbox. But, I have two problems until to complete my app that I need your help to solve.

1) When the app is started, it opens the safari and shows the screen on the left. But I would like the app opens the screen on the right.

[image]

2) I've tried to implement the command

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
```

but I have the error: "No visible @inteface for 'DBSession' declares the selector linkFromController"

I don't know if is necessary to post more information or the complete code. If it is necessary I can do it.

Comment: Do you do: `#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>`?

Comment: Yes. I add the #import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

Comment: I have no trouble in my code calling `[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];` using that `import` statement. Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I tried to use version 1.1 and 1.3.10, both cause the same result.

Comment: This should just work, so maybe you'll need to share some code or start from the example app in the SDK and see if that works.